# Delete DACPAC refactorlog?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I created a DACPAC project and its deployment hasn't proceeded past QA yet. There were only two tables in it. I just did a refactoring and deleted the two tables, then added one new one. Deployment worked locally, however it failed in QA. I'm getting warnings and errors about adding or renaming columns. I wasn't expecting this since I deleted the existing tables and added a new one.

How can I get past these warnings and errors? Is it safe/advisable to delete the refactorlog file? I'm assuming that's the reason the deployment is trying to update from a previous state, instead of just doing a fresh deployment (which is what I want).

I created a pre-deployment script to drop the two original tables. I was hoping the deployment would just create the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by deleting the DB in our QA environment. Then I cleared the contents of the refactorlog in the DACPAC, and redeployed.

I believe another alternative would have been to clear the __RefactorLog table in the DB while also clearing the contents of the refactorlog in the DACPAC, then redeploying.